# Transfer portion of large file from server via SSH

Tags: java, unix, ssh, file-transfer

For our applications, we log to files on several different remote servers depending on the environment. Although the rollover is daily, for some envs, the logs can grow very large (typical high-traffic environment has some logs reach 10 GB daily).

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is functionality similar to the Unix `less` command where I could jump to the last line of the file and read only the newest portions.

I started with `JSch` in Java which worked well for small files, as I could skip to the end minus a set number of bytes and create a new file from the last portion of the log. Code looks something like this:

```
Session session = createJSchSession(user, pass, host, port);
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = createSftpChannel(session);
long filesize = getFileSize(sftpChannel, path);

InputStream in = sftpChannel.get("/path/to/file/hello.log");

in.skip(filesize - bytesToRead);
```

However for larger files, the execution time was no better than if I'd just transferred the file whole. After timing it I determined the `skip` method was the culprit, as it seems to just call `in.read()`  *n* times.

The question is, how do I transfer a small chunk of a text file from a remote server? I'm not even dead-set on using Java, any kind of script would work.

Comment: Why not just use rsync?

Comment: You could use tail to get the end of the file, and then transfer that however, but I think cron and rsync are your friends. And rsync can be made to operate over ssh.

Comment: @fge Uh, no, if only 10 bytes are changed of the 10 GB file, rsync will only download the changes, modulo some small overhead. That's what rsync is *for*.

Comment: @fge [Rsync - Determining which parts of a file have changed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Determining_which_parts_of_a_file_have_changed)

Comment: From the rsync man page: "It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination."

Comment: @fge, if you really want to know check out the rsync algorithm. Rsync calculates the deltas using a check/match mechanism that basically compares appx 150k signatures a la md5 or something similar depending on how you implement. Each signature is sent from client to server and compared.  The signatures are small hence the efficiency aspect of rsync.